# how to display grid of images in table view

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone, what i need is i have to  display 20 images as grid ... is it possible by using tableview and another thing is i have to get selected image id how can i get this pls post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView), which works similar to UITableView but is used for displaying grids.